# Creating a string with an Array, how to prevent "undefined" from printing?

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I am trying to create a string that is made from multiple values within an Array.
here is an example:

```
textArray = []
var wordOne = "Hello";
var wordTwo = "World";

if (wordOne != "foo"){
  textArray.push(wordOne);
}

console.println(textArray[0] + ", " + textArray[1]);
\\It would print out "Hello, undefined"\\
\\ I use 'console.println' since I'm working on Adobe software\\
```

Basically, there are sometimes moments where a value is not added to my array, but I still want to be able to print it out without "Undefined" coming up.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If your value isn't added to your array, how do you want to be able to print it out using the array?

Comment: *I still want to be able to print it out* —print *what* out? If you didn't add a value, there's nothing to print. Just check `textArray[1]` before appending it to the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use join

```js
textArray = []
var wordOne = "Hello";
var wordTwo = "World";

if (wordOne != "foo"){
  textArray.push(wordOne);
}

console.log(textArray.join(', '));
```

Comment: Very concise, and beginner friendly answer.  Thank you!  Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over your array with one of the well-known iteration methods. Then you will not go beyond the array's length. If you have gaps in your array, because you don't assign a value to some array slots, then you can skip those gaps with `forEach`:

```js
var arr = [];
// We leave a gap at [0]
arr[1] = "Test";
// Another gap at [2]
arr[3] = "Trial";

arr.forEach((x, i) => console.log(i, x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only pushing a single element in your array, then accessing two elements, this is why you get `undefined` for the second array access.

Answer (score 0):

you should push both variables that's why you getting an undefined for the index 1 cause your array conatain only one element:

```js
var textArray = [];
const wordOne = "Hello";
const wordTwo = "World";

textArray = [(wordOne !== "foo" && wordOne), (wordTwo !== "foo" && wordTwo)];

console.log(textArray.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a blank string if there is no element:

```
var textArray = []
var wordOne = "Hello";
var wordTwo = "World";

if (wordOne != "foo"){
  textArray.push(wordOne);
}
else {
  textArray.push('')
}

console.println(textArray[0] + ", " + textArray[1]);
//will print: 'Hello,'
```